# HTTPS security is compromised by http://www.mfeuk.co.uk/js/mt/widget/frontend.js

Tags: security, https

can anyone help with this, I'm not anywhere close to calling myself proficient in magento but can normally track most things by **trial and error**,

I have the problem that on my **checkout page** I have HTTPS security is compromised by `http://www.mfeuk.co.uk/js/mt/widget/frontend.js`

ok simple enough, was going to find where it was called from and change to https:, usually does the trick, however I can see it in html if I view source

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mfeuk.co.uk/js/mt/widget/frontend.js"></script>
```

but this does not tell me where in magento backend files this is, could not see anything in local xml. think I'm just looking in the wrong places.

Comment: sorry forgot to add, I'm not sure if the src is on an html file, xml file, css file etc, where should I be looking, I'm not very good with developer tools

Answer (score 2):

When you open the file http://www.mfeuk.co.uk/js/mt/widget/frontend.js you can see in the header that it's part of an 'MT_Widget' extension. You can start looking for the include in this extension.

I am not sure how you've been searching for the file but you can try it via SSH (command line) and

`grep -nr "frontend.js" *`

Answer (score 0):

Download data base and check for this specific string.Probably you added this via some cms block.